# how to resolve axios post request 413 payload too large?

Tags: javascript, axios, body-parser

Iam getting the  error 'axios post request 413 payload too large' when trying to upload images/screenshots of size (700~) kb.I am able to upload small files though.Iam trying do a post operation to upload this file into the blob table in my postgres database.

upload functionality

```
function readFileAsync(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      var base64String = reader.result; 
      console.log(base64String)
     console.log(base64String.substr(base64String.indexOf(',') + 1))

      resolve(base64String.substr(base64String.indexOf(',') + 1));
    };

    reader.onerror = reject;

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
  })
}

async function uploadFile(path, data) {
  try {
    
    let contentBuffer = await readFileAsync(data.chosenfile);
    console.log('content buffer is'+contentBuffer)

    let response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'api/store/blob' + path,
      headers: {'session_id': data.sessionid},
      data: {"id":data.chosenfile.name, "file":  contentBuffer }
    });    

    if (response.status == 200) {
      console.log(response.status);
    }
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code i am converting the file to base64url and from the url i am sending out only the base64 string in the axios payload. Plz help ?

Comment: in my case nginx doesnt allowed too big headers. what server are you using? nginx reverse proxy?

Comment: it is a vue js application and i am using node and npm